# 3rd party excel add-in on Ubuntu

Tags: development

I'm looking to move to Ubuntu. One concern is the use of third party add-ins/VBA for microsoft excel.

http://code.google.com/p/finansu/

Or generally stuff like these:
http://www.skilledup.com/learn/business-entrepreneurship/mostly-free-excel-add-ins/

Will that be supported and how so?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot run Microsoft Office natively in Linux. Microsoft does not provide it, and doesn't seem likely to reconsider this any time soon.

Ubuntu comes with the [Libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) suite which includes a spreadsheet package, which can in general load and work with Excel files. However, Office add-ons and VBA macros are [not supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345159/how-do-i-make-ms-excel-macros-work-in-ubuntu).

Some versions of Office can be run using the [WINE translation layer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-also-games), but this is an unsupported option which cannot be guaranteed to work. People seem in general to be able to run Office 2010 successfully but support for newer versions is less clear.